# Payment Restrictions Upon Checkout Based On Billing/Shipping Address

Tags: checkout, shipping, billing

Our site currently offers 2 types of shipping method; 
1. Credit Card
2. Interac (Debit)

We are looking to accept credit card payment ONLY under the certain conditions:
a. Billing & Shipping postal code match
b. Billing & Shipping does not match but sub-total is under $200.

Otherwise, only interac (debit) will be accepted and customers will be provided with a custom message/notification on the same page that explains 'why'.

So in another words, Interac will be the ONLY option if the customer wants to:
a. Ship to a different address other than billing address AND sub-total is OVER $200.

**I am wondering how I can get this going? Any modules that do this so I can implement easily? Otherwise, it would be great if someone here can provide some tips on how I can achieve this. Thanks a million in advance.**

Comment: You've posted some requirements, but you haven't asked a question.

Comment: Oh I apologize. I must've messed up the copy-and-paste when I asked the question.

I am wondering how I can get this going? Any modules that do this so I can implement easily? Otherwise, it would be great if someone here can provide some tips on how I can achieve this. 

Thanks a million in advance.

Comment: Any input will be appreciated guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can observe the event `payment_method_is_active` and see if the conditions are met.

```
public function paymentMethodIsActive($observer) {
    $event  = $observer->getEvent();
    $method = $event->getMethodInstance();
    $result = $event->getResult();
    $code   = $method->getCode();
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $billingZip = $quote->getBillingAddress()->getPostcode();
    $shippingZip = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
    $ubtotal = $quote->getSubtotal();
    if ($code == "credit card payment code here") {
        if ($billingZip == $shippingZip || $subtotal < 200) {
             $result->isAvailable = true;
        }
        else {
             $result->isAvailable = false;
        }
    }

    if ($code == "debit payment code here") {
        if ($billingZip != $shippingZip && $subtotal >= 200) {
             $result->isAvailable = true;
        }
        else {
             $result->isAvailable = false;
        }
    }
}
```